# reshaping dataframe before plotting and adding labels to the bar plots

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr, reshape

I am trying to reshape my dataset (which represents a balance sheet) in order to plot the evolution of each account.
For reproducibility, here is the structure of my dataset :

```
structure(list(intitule = c("CA sejours", 
"garanties", "+Chiffre d'Affaires hôtelier", "Recettes annexes", 
"=TOTAL CA", "Achats médicaux"
), annee_2019 = c(58523L, 0L, 2474L, 3933L, 64930L, 16532L), 
    annee_2020 = c(49751L, 9396L, 2104L, 2808L, 64059L, 15395L
    ), annee_2021 = c(58681L, 5303L, 2253L, 3059L, 69296L, 15455L
    ), budget_2021 = c(65327L, 0L, 3653L, 3335L, 72315L, 16115L
    ), `rapport_21/20` = c("1,17949388", "0,564389102", "1,07081749", 
    "1,089387464", "1,081752759", "1,003897369"), en_pourcentage = c("17,95%", 
    "-43,56%", "7,08%", "8,94%", "8,18%", "0,39%")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to plot the evolution of the several accounts (denoted in the column "intitule"), this I have to transform my dataset.

I tried this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test <- analytique[,-(6:7)] |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -intitule,
               names_to = "date",
               values_to = "value") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = intitule,
              values_from = value) |> 
  arrange(date)
```

Yet it does not give me the desired output in order to plot the evolution (for instance, plotting the evolution of "CA sejours" from 2019 to 2021).
Here is the structure of my desired output (it is important that the "intitule" rows stay in the same order, as it is a balance sheet : so balance sheet of year 2019, and below balance sheet of year 2020, etc...) :

```
 intitule        value          year

 CA sejours       58523         2019
 garanties        0             2019
```

Finally, i have another question as regards plotting : I cannot seem to put the labels on top of my barplots, even when using geom_text (because when I do, most of the time, as bars do not all have the same heights, labels are either way above or a little beneath, the top of the bar).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Pivot longer has a way of dealing with column names that have the embedded data using .values in the names to argument [explained further here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html)that achieves what I think you are looking for.

```
library(tidyverse)
test <-  analytique[,-(5:7)] %>% 
  as_tibble()  %>%  
  pivot_longer(cols = -intitule,
               names_to = c(".value", "Year"),
               names_sep = "_") %>% 
  rename(Value=annee)
```

You can then plot it and put the labels on top of the bar by specifying the x, and y same as your geom_col, and specify the position dodge argument to get them to the top of each separate column (assuming you wanted to haveall initules for each year together).

```
test %>% ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(Year, Value, fill = intitule), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
    aes(Year, Value, label = Value, group = intitule),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9),
    vjust = -0.5
  )
```

other options for graphing are initules together and different bars for each year:

```
test %>% ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(intitule, Value, fill = Year), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
    aes(intitule, Value, label = Value, group = Year),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9),
    vjust = -0.5
  )
```

or faceting

```
test %>% ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(Year, Value), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
    aes(Year, Value, label = Value, group = Year),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9),
    vjust = -0.5
  )+facet_wrap(~intitule)
```